# Add text to 'wpSelectTasksPage' in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Friends like I do this script text appears only on page "wpselectTasks"
Replacing wpSelectDir to wpSelectTasks
Inno setup compile but nothing appears on the page "wpselectTasks"
Using wpSelectDir will be normal.

```
**(thus appears on the page wpSelectDir)**
var
  avisoLabel: TLabel;
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  aviso: TLabel;
begin

avisoLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
avisoLabel.Left := ScaleX(0);
avisoLabel.Top := ScaleY(190)
avisoLabel.Width := ScaleY(185)
avisoLabel.Height := ScaleY(13)
avisoLabel.Parent:= WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
avisoLabel.Transparent:=true;
avisoLabel.Caption := 'OBS: Sem estes programas instalados o jogo não inicia';
//avisoLabel.AutoSize := True;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
avisoLabel.Visible := CurPageID = wpSelectDir;
end;

**(modifying for wpSelectTasks nothing appears)**

var
  avisoLabel: TLabel;
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
aviso: TLabel;
begin

avisoLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
avisoLabel.Left := ScaleX(0);
avisoLabel.Top := ScaleY(190)
avisoLabel.Width := ScaleY(185)
avisoLabel.Height := ScaleY(13)
avisoLabel.Parent:= WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
avisoLabel.Transparent:=true;
avisoLabel.Caption := 'OBS: Sem estes programas instalados o jogo não inicia';
//avisoLabel.AutoSize := True;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
avisoLabel.Visible := CurPageID = wpSelectTasks;
end;
```

Comment: Try to answer your question from our perspective. What error, where and when ? What error message, on which line and when, at compile time or runtime ? If the error message is related to the compiler error `[ISPP] Undeclared identifier "Color".` then you're just missing the preprocessor define for the `Color` variable, something like `#define Color "000080FF"`.

Comment: Thank TLma fix the script error does not appear on the page wpSelectTasks
Even switching wpSelectdir and WizardForm.SelectDirPage, and to wpSelectTasks WizardForm.SelectTasksPage
Appears on the page SelectDir understood.

Comment: Sorry, I seriously have no idea what's the problem with the script you have (except that missing define, which prevents from compilation). I'd say you're trying to make a label, which should be displayed on more than `wpSelectDir` page, but it's just my guess. Could you edit your question and elaborate on your requirements ?